# SQL CASE when using "AS"

Tags: sql

I am aiming to create a report for our stock system, to show whether we are **IN** stock or **OUT** of stock of products A B & C. Our stock is held in two columns named `physical_qty` and `allocated_qty`

Using this query, I am able to subtract `physical_qty` from `allocated_qty` and show it as `stock`

```
SELECT     
   warehouse, product, description, physical_qty - allocated_qty AS stock
FROM         
   scheme.stockm
WHERE     
   (warehouse = '01') AND (product IN ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

This gives me a numerical value of the amount of stock that we have available to sell.

How can I evaluate if stock is < 1 show **OUT** otherwise show **IN**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT     warehouse, product, description, 
physical_qty - allocated_qty AS stock,
CASE WHEN (physical_qty - allocated_qty) < 1 THEN 'OUT'
ELSE 'IN' END AS Stock_Status
FROM         scheme.stockm
WHERE     (warehouse = '01') AND (product IN ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I managed to do a CASE record for physical_qty OK after lots of trial and error, but was then trying to evaluate the stock column without success.

Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted to showcase your appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CASE WHEN physical_qty - allocated_qt < 1 THEN 'OUT' ELSE 'IN' END
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not realise this would be the way of doing it. I was trying to evaluate stock rather than (physical - allocated) - Thank you for your time.